# Titanium CLI not accepting the .keystore file provided

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I am trying to make android build, target set to build for dist-playstore from Titanium CLI. I am using this command

```
titanium build -p android -b -d /Users/ajeetpratap005/Documents/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/androidTest 
-f -L androidTest -A /Users/ajeetpratap005/android-sdks 
-K /Users/ajeetpratap005/android-test.keystore 
-T dist-playstore -O /Users/ajeetpratap005/Documents/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/androidTest/dist
```

It builds successfully but I am not able to get my build in the output folder. when I checked the build which is getting generated in the build/android/bin folder, it is signed with the default keystore file which is present in the
`<titanium mobile SDK location>/3.0.0.G.A/android/dev_keystore`

How do I make titanium CLI to take my .keystore file and dump the production build to the output folder mention in the command..

Comment: Found the solution- I just removed the option `-b` i.e. for build only, removing that it took my passed keystore and generated a production build.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this document

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Packaging+for+the+Android+Market

There are instructions on the android developer site for generating the certificate key file here: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#cert

See this video for more clarity http://vimeo.com/10278960

Comment: This link is specific to titanium studio, I am not using Titanium Studio. I am using Titanium command line interface to generate and deploy the build. any help on deploying android using Titanium CLI